# Unexpected EOF error while parsing

Tags: python, eof

I'm a novice programmer working on a python assignment and I'm having trouble with an unexpected EOF error while parsing. I'm editing in IDLE, so check module brings up "Unexpected EOF error while parsing" with a red error bar right beside the "#end program" tag.
 I'm wondering if anyone can help me pinpoint the problem:

```
carpet_Cost = 1.20
addmat_Cost = .33
labor_Rate = 18.00
markup = 2.25

print ( "Please enter the total dimensions of the room: " )
width = int ( input ( "Width: ") )
length = int ( input ( "Length: ") )
print ( "Please enter the number of cutouts: " )
cutouts = int ( input ( "Cutouts: ") )
total_Area = width * length
labor_Hours = (( total_Area / 10 * 15 / 60 + 4) )
labor_Cost = labor_Hours * labor_Rate 
matCost = total_Area * (carpet_Cost + addmat_Cost) * markup
for count in loop ( 1, cutouts ):
print ( "Enter the dimensions of the cutout #count: " )
print ( "Width: " )
width = int ( input ( "Width: " ) )
print ( "Length: " )
length = int ( input ( "Length: " ) )
cut_Area = width * length
if cut_Area >= 90:
    mat_Cost = mat_Cost - cut_Area * ( carpet_Cost + addmat_Cost ) * markup
elif cut_Area >= 10:
    mat_Cost = mat_Cost - ( cut_Area * carpet_Cost ) * ( markup - 1 )
    mat_Cost = mat_Cost - ( cut_Area * addmat_Cost ) * markup
else:
    mat_Cost = mat_Cost - ( cut_Area * carpet_Cost ) * ( markup - 1.5 )
    mat_Cost = mat_Cost - ( cut_Area * addmat_Cost ) * markup
    total_Area = total_Area - cut_Area
print ( "Cost estimate: " )
print ( "Carpeted area: " , total_Area )
print ( "Total labor hours: " , labor_Hours )
print ( "Total materials cost: " , mat_Cost )
print ( "Total cost: " , ( mat_Cost + labor_Cost )
#end of program
```

Comment: Missing ) in last statement

Comment: Should be like print ( "Total cost: " , ( mat_Cost + labor_Cost ))

Comment: Many thanks. I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: Your last line has two left parentheses but only one right. Add another right paren or remove the left one--the left one looks unnecessary.